# anchor span element out of screen on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css

in this page http://wobba-jack.com/it/ there is a red banner QUANTO COSTA... with this code styled with this CSS

```css
#stima {width:200%; height:100px; position:absolute; display:block;margin-top:-150px;margin-left: -120px;}
```

```html
<a href="http://wobba-jack.com/it/tuo-tattoo/quanto-costa-un-tatuaggio/"><span id="stima"></span></a>
```

all works fine but the span goes out of screen (I suppose) on mobile phones in vertical mode.

Any help would be very appreciated
Thanks